# pydeps fails to generate dependency graph

Tags: python, dependencies

I'm attempting to use the Python module `pydeps` (installed with `mamba install pydeps`) to analyze the dependencies in my project. However, when I run the command `pydeps main.py` (perhaps "main.py" is not the most informative script name ever), I get the following output:

```
<pydeps_folder>/pystdlib.py:17: UserWarning: stdlib_list does't support Python 3.10 yet, pydeps will use symbols from 3.9 for now.
  warnings.warn(

    ERROR: While opening '<working_directory>/main.svg': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xdg-open' (can be caused by not finding the program to open this file)
```

When I then run the command `firefox main.svg`, I see a graph containing some of the files in my project, but not all of them, so it seems like pydeps succeeded partially. Do I need `xdg-open` for pydeps to work? Or is there any way I can make pydeps work by telling it to just generate the svg file and not try to open it?

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

`xdg-open` in this context is used to open the `main.svg` resulting file. It is a linux utility that opens a file or URL with a preferred/default application. (i.e jpg -> image viewer). In this case it tries to open `main.svg` with your preferred image/svg file viewer.

It sounds like it errors out when trying to open the final result `main.svg`, which is what you're doing by executing:

```
firefox main.svg
```

Therefore I don't think its a partial result of the dependencies.

### References:

- xdg-open docs: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open